# What is (<type>?)?

Tags: c#, types

I was looking through some code the other day and I saw something like (int?) and I dont think Ive ever see that before.  What does it mean when you use a ? after a type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a variation/alternative of the `Nullable<Type>`. Have seen it used a lot with DateTime to avoid the default DateTime value which gives an error in DB columns related to dates. Quite useful actually.

Answer (score 13):

It is short for [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

[Nullable types in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=VS.100).aspx)

This is a generic struct that can wrap a value-type to add the value `null`. To make the use of this type more convenient C# adds quite a bit of compiler-magic. Such as the short-name `T?`, lifted operators,...

The following thread on SO is interesting too: [? (nullable) operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183818/nullable-operator-in-c)

Comment: And the parenthesis is for casting, but you probably knew that.

Comment: I thought the OP used the parentheses as a kind of quotation-marks. But casting makes sense too. To decide that we'd need more context.

Comment: I understand casting, thats not a problem (obviously you didnt know I knew that) so I apologize if I was a bit vague.  My main concern was in fact the Nullable portion.  The "syntactic sugar" is so difficult to google.  Thanks again.

Comment: I agree. Not being able to search for them makes even otherwise trivial problems annoying.

Answer (score 5):

int? is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>`.

Answer (score 4):

That is the shorthand syntax for `Nullable<T>` (or in your case `Nullable<int>`).

This is used when you need value types to be null, such as `int`, `Boolean` and `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

it means Nullable, so our value-type variable can be null

Answer (score 3):

the ? after the type implies that the type can have `null` value besides its normal values.

I've seen the use mostly for database related types where you have `Nullable` columns

Answer (score 3):

As other people have said `int?` is short for `Nullable<int>`.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/05/27/143221.aspx) is a couple of years old now but it's a good explanation of nullable types