# Meaning of the ? operator in C# for Properties

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [? (nullable) operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183818/nullable-operator-in-c)

In System.Windows.Media.Animation I see the code as follows:

```
    public double? By { get; set; }
```

What does the ? operator do here? Does anyone know?

I've tried to google this but it's hard to search for the operator if you don't know what its called by name. I've checked the page on Operators ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) but the ? operator is not listed there.

Thanks!

Comment: nullable type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: normally a question like this would be closed as duplicate, but's its true - very difficult to google for "c# ? operator".

Comment: @RPM1984, even googling for `"double?" c#` doesn't work!

Comment: ...but googling "C# type with question mark" works. Even after typing "c# type with" google suggest the ending.

Comment: Problem here is the (understandable) mistaken belief that ? is an operator, which makes searching for it much harder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `?` is a type decorator. `T?` is the same as [**`Nullable<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), i.e. a nullable value type.

The [documentation of the `By` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.by.aspx) explains why it’s used here:

The property controls how A `DoubleAnimation` progresses; but instead of setting the `By` property, you can also set the `From` and `To` properties (or either) to control animation progress. Every combination of properties (except `To` and `By`) is allowed, so there needs to be a way to signal that a property is *not set* – hence it’s nullable.

> Use the `By` property when you want to animate a value "by" a certain amount, rather than specifying a starting or ending value. You may also use the `By` property with the `From` property.

Comment: Side note: a way to use Nullable types: you should first check if `By.HasValue` is set to `true`, and next access its value with `By.Value`

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty cool. Why would they use it for this class?

Comment: For any number of reasons, so no idea in this case :P

Comment: Awesome thanks. From is also nullable too.

Answer (score 6):

The ? means it's nullable (the value can be set to null.

[Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an operator. Rather, this is a special shorthand syntax for declaring [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) values.

Answer (score 1):

It is nullable propertie, that means that you can set `By = null`, without `?` you'll get error that double cant be null

Answer (score 1):

`?` stands for Nullable types, this qualifies `By` in your case to hold a null value which is not possible for a value type

Answer (score 1):

It means the type is nullable.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

this is syntactic sugar handled by the C# compiler.

It basically treat "double?" as Nullable which allows the value to be null. It basically wraps the double value inside another object.