# difference between decimal? and System.Nullable<decimal>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Nullable<int> vs. int?: Is there any difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028830/c-sharp-nullableint-vs-int-is-there-any-difference)

When using NMG( Nhibernate Mapping generator) when the nullable type are converted I got them as `System.Nullable<decimal>`
whereas by using Visual Nhibernate trail pack I got the nullable types as decimal?

I know what is decimal? does, it is accepted with out throwing errors in case of null values in non-technical terms.

But I could not find out if there is any difference between decimal? and `System.Nullable<decimal>` or not?

Comment: Isn't it just a shorthand alias?

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN - Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

> The syntax **T**? is shorthand for `System.Nullable<T>`, where **T** is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

no difference. `decimal?` is converted to `Nullable<decimal>` at compile time. It can say syntactic sugar

Answer (score 1):

decimal? is a short way of doing System.Nullable this is already answered at [? (nullable) operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183818/nullable-operator-in-c-sharp)

hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between both. type? is only a shortcut notation.