# Task<long?> MethodName()

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all

I've just come across this and can work out what the "Task<long?>" mean. Has anyone got an explanation or can point me to somewhere that explains it.

Thanks

Comment: Which part? The `Task` or the [`Nullable<long>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: Well, it *doesn't* mean that the programmer didn't know if the `Task` would run for a `long` time or not. ^_^;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See MSDN documentation of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>` :

[Asynchronous operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)

`long?` is the type parameter, which is a nullable long. It could be written as

```
Task<Nullable<long>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which part of `Task<long?>` you don't get, so:

[`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) is a generic class used within Task Parallel Library to represent asynchronous operation.

`long?` is a shortcut for [`Nullable<long>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx): [? (nullable) operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183818/nullable-operator-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You would want to read up on [Generics in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx). Basically, generics are a way to create parametrized types. In your example there's a generic type `Task<T>`, which is parametrized with `long?`, which is a nullable long value.