# Reflection and Nullable<T>

Tags: c#

Whenever I call PropertyInfo.GetValue on a Nullable property, I obtain the nullable struct's actual value, not the struct itself. Why is it? Is it baked into the language and only available to the Nullable type or custom classes can have the same thing with other types.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `PropertyInfo.GetValue`'s return type is `object`, which means that all value types are *boxed*.

Now, [nullable types are boxed differently than other types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3775643/87698):

- a nullable value with `HasValue == false` will be boxed to the null reference, and
- a nullable value with `HasValue == true` will be boxed like the underlying non-nullable type. The nullability information is "lost".

---

> Is it baked into the language and only available to the Nullable type [...]

Exactly, (only) the Nullable struct gets special treatment by the CLR.

The reason for this special treatment is explained in detail in the following question. Basically, it boils down to wanting `myNullable == null` and `myBoxedNullable == null` to behave consistently:

- [Boxing / Unboxing Nullable Types - Why this implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387597/87698)